# Problem with mysql console

Tags: mysql

When i login in to my mysql account i doing something like this:

```
 mysql>TRUNCATE MyTable
 ->
 ->
 ->
```

but there is no response informations but only more `->` with every pressed Enter. It is right that there is only more `->` and nothing else with every pressed Enter?
For more i can see on my mysql based page that data which i want to remove is still existing. It is normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to terminate the statement with a semicolon `;`

```
mysql>TRUNCATE MyTable;
```

Comment: Thank You for help. It change something. Now nothing happends. No response and no `->`. How should i understand this behavior?